# slack slash command with node-slack-sdk

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm facing Slack API for the first time.

I'm trying to implement a slash command; I found this tutorial:

https://github.com/slackapi/template-slash-command-and-dialogs

but it seems it doesn't use the [slack node-slack-sdk](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk). After some hour I wasn't able to find anything in the SDK about the slash commands.

Did I missed something or actually the Slack SDK doesn't offer a slash command SDK?

BTW I was able to successfully configure a slash command, I just want to know if it would be possible to do it with [slack node-slack-sdk](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk) to keep coherence in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Slash commands are added in the Slack app's settings page.

```
https://api.slack.com/apps/A1234567/slash-commands?
```

(where `A1234567` is your app ID)

These generate events similar to the Block elements and send POST data to your designated end node.

I don't use an SDK (my CGI is BASH) so I can't speak to how/if they differentiate events generated by slash commands versus other events.

To answer the question, I believe the slash command handling should be documented in here:

```
https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/interactive-messages
```

Comment: <CTRL>+F "slash" and/or <CTRL>+F "command" are enough to see that page doesn't speak about slash commands.

Comment: Is it this?
https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/slash-commands

Comment: Nope @frinklabs , that is Java Bolt SDK, not node-slack-sdk for Node.js (JavaScript)

Comment: How about this?
https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-custom-slack-slash-command-with-nodejs-and-express